Dystopian short story with a noise generator hidden in the mountains
I read a short story in middle school (~1981) about a supposed utopia where everyone remained completely happy and content as long as they took a daily dose of a special medicine. I can't remember why, but one person decided to stop taking this medicine. He soon became aware of an ever-present, grating noise. No one else could hear it--the medicine somehow masked the sound.
Eventually, the noise started to become quite maddening to the man who had stopped taking his medicine. He couldn't stand it. He couldn't sleep. He decided to go out into the night and search for the source of the noise.
As I remember it, he followed the noise into the mountains. There, in a cave, he found a noise generator.
The point of the story was that utopias do not exist. Life cannot be completely happy and without friction. The noise generator was adding the necessary friction to everyone's lives, allowing them to otherwise live happily and free of all aggravation and conflict. But, because of the medicine they were forced to take, they couldn't hear the noise and were led to think this dystopia was utopia.
Do you know the name of the story and/or the author?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What year would this have been, approximately?  (We don't know when you were in middle school.)

Constant hum; https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Machine_Stops

@DavidW Sorry, I probably read this story in 1981. I don't know when it was published. It was in our anthology-style text for the school year.

@Valorum That story has similarities, but based on the plot summary you provided, I don't think that was the one. Thanks, though!
